# ReactJS update cart quantities

Tags: reactjs, onchange, cart

On a React JS project im working on the cart,
the cart object has inside all the products added (1 entries every product) ant the cart page shows the list of product grouped by id with the count of product

cart is a state (shared between components)

the rows of the product list is rendered looping the grouped cart, this way:

```
{cartform.map((single, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <div className="text-lg font-bold">{single[0].name}</div>
              <div >
                {numeral(`${single[0].price}`).format('0.00[,]00 $')}
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  value={single.length}
                  name={single[0].id + '_' + single.length}
                  min="1"
                  className="w-10 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 pl-2"
                  onChange={updateQuantity}
                />
              </div>
               <div>
                <button
                  className="bg-red-500 text-gray-50 px-5 rounded uppercase text-sm"
                  onClick={() => removeFromCart(single[0].id)}
                >
                  Remove
                </button>
              </div>
           </li>
         );
       };
```

the remove button is working correctly, it removes all the entries with the selected id from the cart,
now im struggling with the update quantity field.
the updateQuantity function that i call onChange of the field will call another function (adjustCart)

that basically read the product id, the new value, and the previous value, and if the difference is positive run the addToCart function the right number of times:

```
const adjustCart = ({ product_id, qty, current }) => {
    const product_to_add = qty - current;
    product_id = parseInt(product_id);
    if (product_to_add > 0) {
      setIsLoading(true);
      for (let i = 1; i <= product_to_add; i++) {
        addToCart({ product_id: product_id, qty: 1 });
      }
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

but no matter which number i insert in the field, it only add one and this is becuse something like this

- current value: 1 / I type 5
- onChange is triggered with quantity 5 and previous value 1
- adjustCart run, and loop 4 times
- first time in loop addToCart is run it update the cart and so the value in the quantity field (it is updated to 2) and also the name is updated (with a value like {ID}_2) since the filed changed onChage is triggered again
- this time onChange will have current value=2 and value=2
- so product_to_add=0 and nothing happen

The effect is that no matter which number i type (besides the fact that i can't backspace on the filed, it revert always to 1) it increase only by one.
i came up with two solution, first one is not to trigger onChange but add a "update cart" button that will refresh cart and the second is disabling typing on the qty filed and add a + and - button around it to control the quantity
Both solutions would work but they are not so convincing to me on the user experience site
Also i can trigger the update onfocusout (but how i keep the value updating on view while onchange?)

here is a sample of what i got:
[codesandbox.io/s/confident-torvalds-smg72?file=/src/App.js](http://codesandbox.io/s/confident-torvalds-smg72?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: if add sample code in [codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io/) is great for debugging.

Comment: i see, but its quiete a ton of code/components all linked between them, i see if i can "extract" the part

Comment: Why not `addToCart({ product_id: product_id, qty: N });` with the quantity you want added to the cart? Is `addToCart` an action being dispatched to a redux store? If so may we see your reducer function(s) and how the component connects to the store? I agree, a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example here would be nice, and if you could include a *running* codesandbox that reproduces your issue that we could live debug in that would be great.

Comment: here is a "reduction" of my cart and its behaviour, consider that addToCart functions is also used elsewhere, so i would not change it, maybe i can avoid using it in favour of another one
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-torvalds-smg72?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @popeating .I am not understand problem .if explain for me  I am tell you thanks

Comment: @A.R.SEIF thankyou, i solved changing the data structure